# How is stability for a numerical solution generalized to a system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of ODEs

$$y' = \begin{bmatrix}-6&4\\4&-6\end{bmatrix}y, \quad t\in[t_0, t_e], \quad y(t_0)=y_0$$

I'm asked for what stepsize the explicit Euler method generates a stable solution.

If it would be one ODE I would just find for what stepsize $h$ the stability function $R(z)$ in $$y_{n+1} = R(\lambda h) y_{n}$$ would be less than $1$, but I get confused when it's a system of ODEs. Do I write

$$y_{n+1} = \left(1 + h \begin{bmatrix}-6&4\\4&-6\end{bmatrix}\right) y_n$$

and use the eigenvalues somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of the matrix in the LDE are $λ=-2, -10$. The explicit Euler method is stable for real eigenvalues if $\lambda h\in(-2,0)$ for all $λ$. om this case this means $h<0.2$.

Comment: "The explicit Euler method is stable for real eigenvalues if $\lambda h \in (-2,0) \ \forall \lambda$". Why? Where is that coming from?

Comment: From the inequality $|R(λh)|=|1+λh|<1$ or the more general condition $\|(I+hA)^n\|\to0$ for $n\to\infty$, which is equivalent to the above condition for the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: Why is that equivalent to the above condition? In the next questions I'm asked to do the same thing for implicit Euler so I'd really like to understand the process.

Comment: It is a result of linear algebra that you can compute the spectral radius either as the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue or as $\rho(M)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|M^n\|^{1/n}$ in any operator norm.